# How to get Model attributes from nested json object in Backbone

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

** JSON Data **

```
{
  "data" : [{
      "book" : "first book", -- > i want this via model.get('book');
      "aurthor" : "xyz"
    }
  ]
}
```

** Get json data using jquery Ajax. **

```
var jsonData = {};
$.ajax({
  url : 'booklist.json',
  async : false,
  dataType : 'json',
  success : function (json) {
    jsonData = json.data;
  }
});
```

** Model declaration here **

```
var MyModels = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize : function () {},
    defaults : {}
  });

var modelinstance = new MyModels(jsonData);

modelinstance.get('book'); // it is giving undefined how can i get this value.
```

** Please help where i doing wrong.i am new in Backbone. **

Answer (score 4):

If the data is always a single object wrapped up like that then you'd just add a [`parse` method](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) to your mode:

> **parse** `model.parse(response, options)`
>
> **parse** is called whenever a model's data is returned by the server, in *fetch*, and *save*. The function is passed the raw `response` object, and should return the attributes hash to be *set* on the model.

Something like this:

```
parse: function(response) {
    return response.data[0];
}
```

You can also trigger a `parse` call through the [model constructor](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor) using the `parse: true` option:

> **constructor / initialize** `new Model([attributes], [options])`
>   [...]
>   If `{parse: true}` is passed as an **option**, the **attributes** will first be converted by *parse* before being *set* on the model.

So if you're manually loading the data through a `$.ajax` call then you'd have something like this:

```
success: function (json) {
    var m = new MyModel(json, { parse: true });
    // Do something with m...
}
```